# MySql - delete same field inside multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, web-services

I need to delete student elements from two tables where the stu_id are the same. I followed this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial-aspx/mysql-delete-join/)

```
DELETE s_ezber, s_yem_tem 
FROM s_ezber 
INNER JOIN s_yem_tem 
ON s_ezber.stu_id = s_yem_tem.stu_id 
WHERE s_ezber.stu_id =1901 (s_yem_tem.stu_id )
```

However that is not working correctly. The problem here is that both tables need to contain the same student id, if one doesn't, then this fails.
What I would like it to do is to delete the row if it exists in either or both tables. How can I handle it with only one query ?

Comment: Use two queries in a transaction.

Comment: Or look at the manual and read about JOINs -- Maybe you would benefit from a FULL OUTER JOIN here...

Comment: @Stuart can you share a link to `FULL OUTER JOIN` documentation for MySQL?

Comment: DELETE s_ezber, s_yem_tem FROM s_ezber FULL OUTER JOIN s_yem_tem ON s_ezber.stu_id = s_yem_tem.stu_id WHERE s_ezber.stu_id =1901 gives error  (Unknown table 's_ezber' in MULTI DELETE )

Comment: You have to simulate one in MySQL. So there are no docs. However in SQL (as the author has tagged) you can.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel looking for whatu have adviced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete s_ezber, s_yem_tem
from (select 1901 as stu_id) sub
left join s_ezber using(stu_id)
left join s_yem_tem using(stu_id);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/ESX91655

That should have the same effect as two queries in a transaction:

```
start transaction;
delete s_ezber   where stu_id = 1901;
delete s_yem_tem where stu_id = 1901;
commit;
```